# When I set the CanonicalKey or CanonicalUrl for a dynamic node, I get a NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using MVCSiteMapProvider v4.6.22 and have a dynamic node provider for one of my controllers.

Something like:

```
public class ProviderDetailsNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        foreach (var provider in providers)
        {
            var dn = new DynamicNode()
            {
                Title = provider.Name,
                ParentKey = "ParentKey",
                Key = $"provider_master_{provider.ID}",
                CanonicalUrl = "/url/something"
            };

            dn.RouteValues.Add("myRouteParamName", "myRouteParamValue");

            yield return dn;
        }
    }
}
```

Without setting the `CanonicalKey` or `CanonicalUrl` properties of the `DynamicNode`, I get the correct behaviour. However I now wish to have multiple URLs pointing at the same content so I need to utilise the Canonical URL features of MVCSiteMapProvider.

If I attempt to set the `CanonicalUrl` as in the above snippet, or the `CanonicalKey` (my preferred choice), then when I attempt to use the helper methods, such as:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

I get a `NullReferenceException` - it's the `@Html.MvcSiteMap()` which returns null.

What am I doing incorrectly, why do I get this `NullReferenceException` just by setting these properties against my dynamic nodes?

I'm using the `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5` package, in an MVC6 application. I can't see a newer version on Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

MVC 6 is not yet supported, as per the [issue on NuGet](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/394).